# English words with the most consonants, all voiced or all unvoiced

Tags: word, open-ended

What English words containing only voiced or only unvoiced consonants contain the most?

Count each consonant as many times as it appears.

Note that this is a question about the sounds (phonemes) contained in spoken English words, not letters of the alphabet!

Consonants are either voiced (spoken with vibration of the vocal cords) or unvoiced (spoken without it). For example the sounds usually represented by *b*, *d* and *v* are voiced, whereas those usually represented by *p*, *t* and *f* are unvoiced. Voiced consonants can convey a feeling of softness; unvoiced ones, strength.

*Captious* contains 4 consonants, all unvoiced: /c/, /p/, /ʃ/, /s/.
*Bamboozled* contains 6, all voiced: /b/, /m/, /b/, /z/, /l/, /d/.

Can you do better?

Unvoiced consonants:
/f/, /k/, /p/, /s/, /t/,
/h/
/ʃ/ (***sh****oe*),
/θ/ (***th****in*),
/tʃ/ (***ch****ip*) (count as single)

Voiced consonants:
/v/, /g/, /b/, /z/, /d/,
/l/, /m/, /n/, /r/, /w/, /y/,
/ʒ/ (*vi****s****ion*),
/ð/ (***th****at*),
/dʒ/ (***g****em*) (count as single)
/ŋ/ (*si****ng***)

Let's pronounce *where* and *wear* the same. /hw/ is an unvoiced-voiced pair and therefore could not appear in the words we want anyway, and we will ignore /ʍ/, the unvoiced partner of /w/ that appears in some people's pronunciation of *where*.

Comment: You should probably give clarification or restrictions on what is considered an English word. People on this Stack love their loopholes.

Comment: @KSmarts - Any word listed in an English dictionary will be fine.

Comment: I thought this was a good puzzling question, of a type I haven't seen before, but perhaps there's little interest here in spoken words as strings of phonemes rather than written words as strings of letters? (One thing I like about puzzling is that it can be educative in a range of fields.) Maybe I should post it to English Language and Usage SE and tag it "poetry"? Edit: actually on further thought I may offer a bounty to try to make phonemically themed questions more popular here!

Comment: This is a very frustrating puzzle. I keep thinking of or finding almost-answers, like long words of all voiced consonants, except for a single "s" or "ch" somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Someone could write a program for it.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code - Yes, if they had a digital phonemic dictionary.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code - Or if they wrote or got a program to output the pronunciation of English words in phonetics. Any idea whether there's an open source one?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7 unvoiced consonants:

*Hypaspists*: h, p, s, p, s, t, s

Runners-up with 6:

*Ecstatics*: k, s, t, t, k, s.
*Expects*: k, s, p, k, t, s.
*Fisticuffs*: f, s, t, k, f, s.
*Pacifists*: p, s, f, s, t, s.
*Sexists*: s, k, s, s, t, s.
*Specificity*: s, p, s, f, s, t.

7 voiced consonants:

*Invulnerable*: n, v, l, n, r, b, l.
*Unendangered*: n, n, d, n, j, r, d.
*Underminers*: n, d, r, m, n, r, z.
*Undependable*: n, d, p, n, d, b, l.
*Undeservedly*: n, d, z, r, v, d, l.
*Unremembered*: n, r, m, m, b, r, d.
*Unreservedly*: n, r, z, r, v, d, l.

*Unendangeredly* has 4 hits on Google but isn't in any dictionary.
*Undermobilized* also has a few hits.

Comment: Why not "specificities"?

Comment: The last sound of "specificities" is /z/.

Comment: I don't know much of anything about phonetics or linguistics, but according to the Wikipedia page on voicing, "The /z/ phoneme, ... can actually be pronounced as either the [s] phone or the [z] phone because /z/ is frequently devoiced in fluent speech, especially at the end of an utterance." This seems to say that the voiced consonant /z/ can be spoken unvoiced, which doesn't make any sense to me (why is it a voiced consonant, then?). It's no wonder that I haven't been able to come up with an answer for this question.

Comment: @KSmarts - There's a lot of space for linguistic scholars to be quite tendentious. Many categories have to be quite woolly. For example, there's no definition of _syllable_ that makes clear exactly where every syllable starts or ends. Categories are defined with differing amounts of abstractness by different scholars. I think what this person meant is that what 'in theory' (for some value of 'theory') 'should' be /z/ is sometimes pronounced with less or no voice by some speakers.

Comment: (continued) I would say that if it's completely devoiced then the sound is /s/, but a few people would go all Platonic (saying the ideal of /z/ is still expressed) ... or is it postmodern (truth is a perception)? Remember that pronunciation of individual phonemes does vary. The usual question is whether or not the differences can differentiate between two words. If it were up to me, I'd just say that saying that the last phoneme in _specificities_ is sometimes /s/ would, in our context, be pushing it a bit too far.

Comment: Right, I was going by which phonemes are present, rather than which sounds actually end up being pronounced.

Comment: @Bret - I would accept this answer and then change the acceptance to another one if someone beats 6 unvoiced 7 voiced, but since there's a bounty I'll just say that this excellent answer is top for the time being.

Comment: @Bret -- did you generate this list automatically?

Comment: @ThePopMachine No, just some thinking and trial and error. Note the bias toward "un-" words in the voiced category.

Comment: Do Gollum pronunciations count? Like, "Hypaspistses"

Answer (score 3):

Here are some improvement/additions to @Bret's answer.

**Voiced (9 letters)**

- brobdingnagians: b, r, b, d, g, n, g, n, z
- environmentalism: n, v, r, n, m, n, l, z, m (in t-dropping pronunciations)

**Voiced (8 letters)**

- alexandrines: l, g, z, n, d, r, n, z
- bilingualism: b, l, n, g, w, l, z, m

**Unvoiced (7 letters)**

- statistics: s, t, t, s, t, k, s
- sophisticates: s, f, s, t, k, t, s
- stethoscopes: s, t, θ, s, k, p, s